# javascript value is null

Tags: javascript

Ok so here it goes im totally lost a bit and im a beginner.

A friend of mine has a radio website, it a really old site.

Has a form where he can uptade the users.

This form has a radio button named dj and values yes or no.

and on the index page it shows the list of the users.

and i would like to do if this radio button is checked, than add a small dj image after the users name.

but no matter what i do im always getting the value null.

the header and footer are included in both of the files, if im right that suppose to give the result no? i placed in the footer its giving back nulll as result

```
var dj = document.getElementById("dj");
alert(dj.value);
```

i tried wit the wondow.onload function nothing happens.

I would really like to do this in javascript for practis.

Could somebody please explain what im missing and why i cant get this to show on the index? and is it possible ot make it?

Be gentlle please im a really big beginner :)

Comment: What happens when you `alert(dj);`

Comment: @Side have you set id of one of the radio button as "dj" not name. name and id are different things

Comment: the id is set, and on the edit page if i run it in the console its ok returns the value yes, but if i place it in the footer returns null

Comment: and i want this to access gobaly

Comment: View the source of the page from the browser and confirm that the ID hasn't been altered.

Comment: Your javascript looks correct. Either the script is executing before the element is inserted into the DOM, or the element does not have id="dj", or something else is manipulating the element before your script runs.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 alert(dj.checked);
```

It will alert true or false depending upon the status of radio button if you created your radio button smiler to this

```
<input type="radio" name="music" value="test" id="dj">
```

Comment: thank zou, zes it  is similar, and works fine, but m problem is, in i run the script on the edit.php its ok returns the walue, but if i run it on the footer nothing

Answer (score 1):

I've created a working example (though not elegant) which illustrates exactly what needs to be done since you've mentioned you're a beginner.

http://sente.cc/misc/radio_button_test.html

The code is:

```
 <html>
   <head>
     <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
     <title>radio buttons</title>
     <script>
       var testit = function(){
         var radioyes = document.getElementById('idyes');
         var radiono = document.getElementById('idno');

         if (radioyes.checked){alert(radioyes.value);}
         if (radiono.checked){alert(radiono.value);}
       };
     </script>
   </head>
   <body>
     <form>
       DJ:
       <br>
       <input id="idyes" type="radio" name="sex" value="yes" /> Yes<br />
       <input id="idno"  type="radio" name="sex" value="no" /> No
     </form>
   </body>
   <span style="background:lightblue;" onclick="javascript:testit()">click here to run javascript</span>
 </html>
```

There are much better ways of going about this. (like iterating through all the radio elements until you come across one with a `.checked` property of `true`)

Answer (score 0):

Probably both radio buttons have the same ID, so such code can't work.

Instead, try this: (assuming you have only one form)

```
var oForm = document.forms[0];
var value = "";
for (var i = 0; i < oForm.elements.length; i++) {
    var el = oForm.elements[i];
    if (el.type == "radio" && el.name == "dj" && el.checked) {
        value = el.value;
        break;
    }
}
alert("selected value: " + value);
```

The code is pretty much straightforward.

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/vNCur/).

Answer (score -2):

I would reference the jQuery library and use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert($("#dj").val());
});
```

Comment: "I would really like to do this in javascript for practis."

Comment: There is obviously another underlying problem that cannot be solved by "Using jQuery"